# CImg - Get inverse FFT of an image

Tags: c++, image-processing, fft, cimg

I am trying to implement the spectral approach to compute a saliency map for an image, but I can't seem to get the inverse FFT working.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    const char * input_file = "img/pic.png";

    CImg<unsigned char> * input = new CImg<unsigned char>(input_file);

    resize_fft(*input); //Resize the image for the FFT
    CImg<unsigned char> gray = any2gray(*input); //to single-channel grayscale image
    free(input);

    CImgList<unsigned char> fft = gray.get_FFT();
    CImg<unsigned char>::FFT(fft[0], fft[1], true);
    fft[0].save("img/fft.png");

    return 1;
}
```

In the end, fft.png is just a black image file. I can't find any example of anybody computing inverse fft using CImg... Does someone have any clue ?

Thanks a lot !
Robin

Comment: Have you tried normalising, or contrast-stretching the result - they are typically very dark...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common issue that can arise for a wide range of images is that the FFT of the image cannot be represented (or loose too much information to be of practical use) with the limited range of `unsigned char` . You can avoid this by performing the FFT computations with an intermediate `float` image:

```
// convert from unsigned char to float to support larger range of values
CImg<float> fft_in = gray;

// Forward transform
CImgList<float> fft = fft_in .get_FFT();

// Inverse transform
CImg<float>::FFT(fft[0], fft[1], true);

// Normalize back to unsigned char range (0,255) and save
fft[0].normalize(0,255).save("img/fft.png");
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Now that I think about it it seems logical...
Thanks a lot !